# Writing a debugger, debuggee isn't properly closing

Tags: debugging, winapi

I'm trying to write a debugger.

My problem is, debuggee windows is left open even after the ExitProcess in it is called. Debugger receives EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT, but debuggee window is still visible and does not react to anything. It does goes away with the closing of debugger though.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: faster of all you not call ContinueDebugEvent on EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you!

Comment: RbMm, copypaste your answer as answer if you care about reputation, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as RbMm said, "faster of all you not call ContinueDebugEvent on EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT"

RbMm, copypaste your answer as answer if you care about reputation, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm really having a hard time comprehending, what that quoted text is supposed to mean. Since you apparently understood it, would you mind rewording it?